# How linq between 2 lists by StartsWith

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list of string.

```
var list1 = new List<string> { "1", "12", "21", "34", "22" };
var list2 = new List<string> { "1", "2" };
```

I Need select items of list1 where item StartsWith by items in list2 : `"1", "12", "21", "22"`

```
//foreach solution :  "1", "12", "21", "22"
var result1 = new List<string>();
foreach (var item in list2)
    result1.AddRange(list1.Where(x => x.StartsWith(item)).ToList());

//linq solution : "1"
var result2 = list1.Where(x => list2.Contains(x)).ToList();
```

How can I get `result1` by linq solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use a combination of `Where` with `Any` like:

```
var query = list1.Where(s1 => list2.Any(s2 => s1.StartsWith(s2))).ToList();
```

and you will end up with:

```
{"1","12","21","22"}
```

another option is doing the cross join and then query like:

```
var query = from s1 in list1
            from s2 in list2
            where s1.StartsWith(s2)
            select s1;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
var result = list1.Where(x => list2.Any(y => x.StartsWith(y)).ToList();
```

Answer (score 0):

Using [NinjaNye.SearchExtensions](https://www.nuget.org/packages/NinjaNye.SearchExtensions/) you can do something like the following

```
using NinjaNye.SearchExtensions;


var query = list.Search(x => x).StartsWith(list2);
```